# Configuration file access: syntax to allow relay from all networks/addresses

Tags: sendmail

In the `/etc/mail/access` file, for the `Connect` key to permit relay, what is the notation that can be used to indicate that I want to permit relay for senders from all networks?

PS: I need it to open up a server temporarily for purposes of a training class.

Comment: Why do you want to make your sendmail an open spam/relay?  Quite likely you confused terminology.

Comment: I am conducting a class to demonstrate the SMTP protocol. I have set up `sendmail` on a Raspberry Pi for the duration of the class for the students to send out a mail command by command.

Comment: IMHO it would make more sense to allow **relaying to** a few email domains or even a few email addresses. [Allowing relay to full email addresses in access table requires extra parameter `relaytofulladdress` to `FEATURE(access)` in sendmail.mc file]